# Multiple Peer connection Web-RTC in android issue

Tags: webrtc, multipeer-connectivity, rtcpeerconnection, webrtc-android

When I create multiple peer connections for group audio call. All users connect with each other but only first receiver get the sound of caller and getting below issue. We want to send the media with multiple peer connections.

```
2019-06-28 14:49:09.738 21453-21453/com.wisitech.automobilechat E/onSC: FAR
2019-06-28 14:49:09.808 21453-22518/com.wisitech.automobilechat E/AudioRecord: start() status -38
2019-06-28 14:49:09.810 21453-22518/com.wisitech.automobilechat E/WebRtcAudioRecord: WebRtcAudioRecord: Start recording error: AUDIO_RECORD_START_STATE_MISMATCH. AudioRecord.startRecording failed - incorrect state :1
2019-06-28 14:49:09.822 21453-22518/com.wisitech.automobilechat E/PCRTCClient: onWebRtcAudioRecordStartError: AUDIO_RECORD_START_STATE_MISMATCH. AudioRecord.startRecording failed - incorrect state :1
2019-06-28 14:49:09.822 21453-22518/com.wisitech.automobilechat E/PCRTCClient: Peerconnection error: AudioRecord.startRecording failed - incorrect state :1
2019-06-28 14:49:09.822 21453-22518/com.wisitech.automobilechat E/libjingle: (audio_record_jni.cc:170): StartRecording failed
2019-06-28 14:49:09.938 21453-21453/com.wisitech.automobilechat E/onSC: FAR
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also getting same issue during connecting the call between more than two person.
Caller get voice of all receivers but only first receiver get voice of caller.